# How to instantiate com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to process csv file present in cloud bucket and insert its data in a BQ table. I found following piece of code but I am not sure how I can instantiate com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table  for a given table name

```
    com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table table = null;
    com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job job = table.load(FormatOptions.csv(), sourceUri);
        com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job completedJob = job.waitFor(WaitForOption.checkEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
          WaitForOption.timeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
      if (!(completedJob != null && completedJob.getStatus().getError() == null)) {
          throw new InterruptedException("Unable to load file from bucket into BQ");
      } 
    return job;
```

Comment: @shama - did the snippet work?

Comment: @polleyg: Yes, it worked, sorry I forgot to update this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet taken from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java).

```
[imports]

BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
TableId tableId = TableId.of("dataset", "table");
Table table = bigquery.getTable(tableId);

[..]
```

Side note - that is an Alpha client library you are using. Just so you know.